# How oAuth is related to user account

Tags: smartsheet-api

I went through the documentation of smartsheet api third party authentication.
Steps are :

```
1. Register into developer tool.
2. Create an app.
3. note down client id.
4. From the application code call "authorize" api with client id.
5. smart sheet will redirect to consent page.
```

Now here I am confused. as to the API we will be called using Application's client id, how it is related to user who is access my web application. Because the app which I created in developer tool has access, api will works. Doesn't matter who is logged into my web application and has access to work sheet or not.

How smartsheet will know which user is trying to access the sheets because in the API we are just passing Developer App client id.
Or How Developer App can access logged in user's sheet.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consent page will urge the user to login the system if the user has not logged in the system yet. Then, the system will ask the user whether he grants permissions to the client application or not. If permissions are granted, the system will issue a token which denotes "The user has granted the permissions to the client application". This is a basic concept of OAuth. Please read *"[The Simplest Guide to OAuth 2.0](https://medium.com/@darutk/the-simplest-guide-to-oauth-2-0-8c71bd9a15bb)"*.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this section of the documentation: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#third-party-app-development
Essentially, your application grants user access-scopes on a per-user basis. Your app needs a developer account. Your users need some kind of Smartsheet plan. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked their documentation. I did following things: created developer account using an email. created one test app. which gave me client id. Now if I create a web application and use test app's client id to call authorize api. when any one access my web application, how smartsheet authorize api will know, who is accessing my web application because web application will always pass hardcoded client id.